# Confluent platform - basic commands need sudo?

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying out the open sourced Confluent platform in AWS linux server running (centOS 7.x). After doing a yum install on the oss (open source version) version as root, it was quite straight forward to start the services with

```
confluent start
```

command.

The question I have is - when I log into same server as non-root user and I try to execute below command it returns all services are down.

```
confluent status
```

If I execute the same with sudo access, it shows all services are up and running. Why does the basic confluent cli commands need sudo access?

If I start the services as root, shouldn't all users be able to see that the services are up and running without sudo?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Confluent CLI uses a `tmp` folder, so my guess is that your two users (`root` and your own) are getting different `tmp` environments, and thus when it tries to determine if the stack is up or not, it does so in the scope of that tmp environment.

You can force it to use a single env by setting the environment variable `CONFLUENT_CURRENT` before invoking the `confluent` script. E.g. `export CONFLUENT_CURRENT=/Users/Robin/cp/confluent-3.3.0/tmp/`

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-cli/issues/40 / https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-cli reference this behaviour